# Inverted tail command?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, tail, text, text-formatting

Basically, piping a command or block of text to something like: `tail -n 3` (for example), will *print **only** the last three lines* to `stdout`. Is there an equivalent, or similar method for doing the exact inverse of that? So that, in this example, it would *print **all** **but** the last three lines* to `stdout`.

Comment: @don_crissti you are correct, I was confusing `-n -3` with `-3` (which is equivalent to `-n 3`.

Comment: Nice one. Yeah that's what i was after. I didn't realize you could specify a negative integer as an argument to `head` like that. Conversely, `tail` doesn't seem to accept negatives in the same way. If you want to go ahead and stick it in an answer, I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @don_crissti's comment; if you found this helpful, please upvote his comment.

If I have file `a` containing:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and I want to get all **but the last three lines** I can run `head -n -3` on it to produce the following:

```
# head -n -3 a
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it could be something like this(not very elegant but tested it and it works):

```
a=$(wc -l <file.txt);a=$((a-3));sed ''$a'q;' file.txt
```

wc -l returns the number of the lines of the file. The number of the lines is now assigned to a.

since we want all but the last 3 lines, we are reducing a and then using sed to print until the ath line of the file.

Comment: Shorter as `wc -l <file.txt` and faster as `head -n $a file.txt`

Comment: @don_crissti Nice one, I edited my answer with your suggestion. Cheers! :)